# How to Mock HandlerThread in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-handlerthread

How can i mock `HandlerThread`in Android. I am creating `HandlerThread` in constructor of a class. I need to mock the `HandlerThread` to write test case. Here is my code

```
 HandlerThread("TimeoutHandlerThread").apply {
    start()
    workHandler = WorkHandler(looper)
}
```

Didn't find any clue.

How can i mock this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Gabe says, the problem here is with your design. Use dependency injection to provide dependencies that you can mock.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock something internal to a class.  You can mock things you pass into the class.  The solution to mocking this is not to create the HandlerThread in the class but to pass it in as a parameter to the constructor.  Then it can be mocked however you wish.